# Why test to see if sessions has been started

Tags: php, session

This is from the [official php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php):

> session_start() creates a session or resumes the current one based on a session identifier passed via a GET or POST request, or passed via a cookie.

I see code in all of the php programming books I have read that starts the page of code with just:

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
```

But I see posts here where developers are checking to see if a session has been started.

```
if (session_id() == '') {
    session_start();
}
```

The manual seems to suggest that `session_start()` does the checking for you and if it isn't started, then it starts it itself.

So, who is correct?

Comment: I believe both. You should never assume something is the way you think it is, that is probably why some check it and have code for when it is not started.

Comment: For multiple reasons, too many in fact.

Comment: Most likely people who are checking if sessions have already been started, are tossing random libraries and frameworks at the top of their scripts and don't fully understand what those packages are already doing... and thus just do a conditional 'in case it isnt'.

Comment: Code I was referring to: if (session_id() == '') { session_start() };

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because you cannot have `sesseion_start()` called more than once on the same script.

Lets assume that we have an script `index.php` witch includes another script `frontController.php` and both have a session start

If you do not verify and try to start another session, PHP will throw a notice like the following:

`A session had already been started - ignoring session_start() in frontController.php:80`

Answer (score 0):

Because you can't start the session twice:

```
session_start();
session_start();
```

> Notice: session_start(): A session had already been started - ignoring

When docs say that *`session_start()` creates a session or resumes the current one* it's implicit that an already started session cannot be created nor resumed.

This can be a sign of messy design or a defensive coding approach against potential `session.auto_start` being enabled.

I particularly never do it. If unsure about `session.auto_start` it's simpler to just disable the directive at application level.